# CSS keyframe animation on SVG is smearing background in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

EDIT: It seems to be a issue on WebKit, [I submitted a bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219379#c0) in case you case you want follow it and see any updates.

I have box element that when clicked an SVG element (shaped as an "X") is added as a child. After the svg renders, its shapes are animated by CSS keyframes. The animation involves two dots that transform into lines.

In Safari, as the dots move and transform, they smear the background ( leave behind pixel trails ) and it stays after the animation is done.

[image: SVG animation finished, but leaves behind smeared background]

I've tried adding `will-change: transform, animation;` for gpu animation.
`transform: translateZ(0)` to place it on a new layer.

Shows bug on IOS Safari 12.4.7+

```js
const cell = document.querySelector(".cell");

cell.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cell.innerHTML = svgCross();
});


function svgCross() {
  return `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 26.4583 26.4583" version="1.1" id="svg8-cross-P1">
  <g filter="url(#drop-shadow-filter)">
    <g class="animate__left-dot" fill="url(#a-crossLeftDot-P1)">
      <circle cx="6.4855" cy="19.9915" r="1.3368"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="animate__right-dot" fill="url(#a-crossRightDot-P1)">
      <circle r="1.3368" cy="19.9915" cx="19.9756"></circle>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g fill="none" stroke-width="2.6458" stroke-linecap="round" filter="url(#drop-shadow-filter)">
    <g stroke="url(#c-cross-P1)" transform="translate(0 -.0191)">
      <path d="M 6.4855595,6.4855597 19.972772,19.972772" class="animate__right-line"></path>
    </g>
    <g stroke="url(#d-cross-P1)" transform="translate(0 -.0191)">
      <path d="M 19.972772,6.4855597 6.4855597,19.972772" class="animate__left-line"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
`;
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes Lines-A {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 30px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes Lines-A {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 30px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes Right-Dot-A {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes Right-Dot-A {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes Left-Dot-A {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes Left-Dot-A {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #2420ad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cell:hover {
  background: purple;
}

.svg-defs {
  height: 0;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform, animation;
}

svg .animate__right-dot {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: Right-Dot-A 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.58, 1);
          animation: Right-Dot-A 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 13.2291665px 13.2291665px;
          transform-origin: 13.2291665px 13.2291665px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  /*-> -90deg*/
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
}

svg .animate__left-dot {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: Left-Dot-A 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.58, 1);
          animation: Left-Dot-A 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 13.2291665px 13.2291665px;
          transform-origin: 13.2291665px 13.2291665px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  /*-> -90deg*/
}

svg .animate__left-line,
svg .animate__right-line {
  opacity: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: 30;
  -webkit-animation: Lines-A 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.58, 1);
          animation: Lines-A 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
          animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="cell"></div>

  <div class="svg-defs">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="defs-collection" height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <defs>
        <filter id="drop-shadow-filter" height="100" width="100" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="1" flood-color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)" result="flood"></feFlood>
          <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="composite1"></feComposite>
          <feGaussianBlur in="composite1" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur>
          <feOffset dy="1.8" result="offset"></feOffset>
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset" result="composite2"></feComposite>
        </filter>
        <filter id="drop-shadow-filter-slash" height="100" width="100" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="1" flood-color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)" result="flood"></feFlood>
          <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="composite1"></feComposite>
          <feGaussianBlur in="composite1" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur>
          <feOffset dy="0.7" result="offset"></feOffset>
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="offset" result="composite2"></feComposite>
        </filter>
        <linearGradient id="b-cross-P1">
          <stop class="color-primary-cross-P1" offset="0" stop-color="#0cf"></stop>
          <stop class="color-secondary-cross-P1" offset="1" stop-color="#5fd"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="a-cross-P1">
          <stop class="color-secondary-cross-P1" offset="0" stop-color="#5fd"></stop>
          <stop class="color-primary-cross-P1" offset="1" stop-color="#0cf"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y2="19.9728" x2="6.4856" y1="13.2292" x1="13.2292"
          id="d-cross-P1" xlink:href="#a-cross-P1"></linearGradient>
        <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y2="22.7431" x2="21.9646" y1="11.6221" x1="11.6221"
          id="c-cross-P1" xlink:href="#b-cross-P1"></linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="a-crossLeftDot-P1">
          <stop class="color-primary-crossLeftDot-P1" stop-color="#0cf"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="a-crossRightDot-P1">
          <stop class="color-secondary-crossRightDot-P1" stop-color="#5fd"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a css solution, but given your credibility, I'm filing one right now

Comment: If you *really* need a workaround now, [here is a very ugly one](https://jsfiddle.net/wvtsep6b/), but I don't feel comfortable posting it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, I'm going to make a special case and use this solution only for this one project I'm working on. Hopefully Webkit solves this bug

Comment: @CalebTaylor mind linking the bugreport here for future reference? (I think it could even be the answer.)

Comment: @Kaiido I think any workaround that solves problem counts, so perhaps the "micro-blur backdrop-filter animation to force full area redraw" as much as dirty it may feel is also worth noting in answers.

Comment: @myf updated the post to include bug report https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219379#c0

Comment: @myf I feel this would make for an ephemeral answer only. Not sure how useful it is, and I always hesitate to post these (even when less hacky) because it might need to be updated in the future. Feel free to post it on my behalf though if you have the energy of keeping it up to date, it seems you understood quite well how it works. BTW, on a second though using opacity(0.999) to opacity(1) as backdrop-filter here would be even better since that would actually do nothing but force the redraw.